# How to validate textbox type=number by DataAnnotation

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, html

I have the form

```
<input type="number" id="txtnumber"/>
<input type="submit" value ="submit" id="btnsubmit"/>
```

I want to validate if number greater than 10 the increase button in textbox number and the button submit will be disable.How to user with dataanotation or jquery.

Comment: To restrict the increase button, you could use the attribute max="10" in the input, but it won´t disable the button. The user still can type in the field, so handle the change event of the input e check the val() to disable the submit.

Comment: @Murilo Amaru Gomes,can i user dataannotation on MVC,and how can disable the increase button in this textbox

Comment: @Norlihazmey Ghazali ,in the textbox ,this is type=number,this will have 2 button increse and decrease step=1,i want to validate it

Comment: I think the increase button that he is saying is the native for type number on chrome for example

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Range Attribute

```
  public class YourClass
  {

     [Range(2,5)]
     public int MyNumber { get; set; }
  }
```

in your view:

```
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MyNumber)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MyNumber)
```

Add the the validation scripts:

```
     bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                 "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
                 "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));
```

It will not disable the increase button and if you want to disable the submit button you should use jquery, but if you do this the jquery validate will not let the users submits until the form been invalid

Answer (score 0):

Is it this is what you want??

**For HTML you need to add max attribute:**

```
<input type="number" id="txtnumber" max="10"/>
<input type="submit" value ="submit" id="btnsubmit"/>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).on('keyup','#txtnumber', function(){
   var no = parseInt($(this).val());
   if(no > 10)
   {    
       $('#btnsubmit').prop('disabled', true);
   }
   else
   {

     $('#btnsubmit').prop('disabled', false);
   }
});
```

Comment: If i validate by jquery,what happen if the client disable javascritpt.And in the text box type= number ,can i disable 2 mini button increase and decrese

Comment: You need to make validation in server side also, all you need to do is do not rely on client side itself. If you make input type as number, then it is impossible to hide, unless you hide those button using css.

Comment: that's why I show on my answer the Range data annotation, which will validate on server and client